# jQuery parseInt() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code to add elements to my table and that part works perfectly fine. However, I want to add up the values of the last column in order to later print that on another part of the page. parseInt doesn't work for some reason (the values don't come back as integers and stay as strings, is there anything I have done wrong? Again, adding to the table works perfectly fine.

```
var hourC = 0;
var hourC =+ parseInt($(".hourCount").text(), 10);
alert(hourC);
```

**Edit:**

When I print the values of the variable hourC they don't add up to the previous value, they just stay next to each other. Example: 1 + 1 = 11 rather than 2. I don't see where my issue is and the answer for debugging didn't help since I still got the same result.

**Final Edit:**

I achieved what I wanted now through a different medium, I created an array and pushed the values into the array and then I used "join" to solve the issue.

If interested in what I was asking for here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevincc0418/w18p8nnt/) with the final result. (You can just change the console.log to alert)

Comment: What makes you think they aren't coming back as integers?

Comment: what did you get the value in $(".hourCount").text(), your fiddle didn't go to the else part

Comment: They don't come back as integers, because when I do the sum of all of the elements that come in instead of being 1+1=2 it's 1+1=11

Answer (score 2):

Basic debugging skills.

`parseInt` works -- its a well tested function.  If it broke in a browser, a lot of people would notice.

However, you haven't given any way to figure out what is going on with your code, since the real problem *MUST* be here:

```
$(".hourCount").text()
```

That must not contain whatever value you think it does.

Split your code up and use the debugger, or even console log, to see what the values are.

```
var hourC = 0;
var strValue = $(".hourCount").text();
alert(["strValue = ", strValue]);
hourC = parseInt(strValue, 10);
alert(hourC);
```

Comment: It seems like you should have closed for lack of a MCVE, since this doesn't answer the question except to say to do some debugging.

Comment: This debugging question does not include an MCVE, a clear problem statement, expected output, actual output, or example input, yet it is worthy of an answer on how to debug code? This fundamentally *does not* answer the question "is there anything I have done wrong?"

Comment: This keeps giving me 1+1= 11 rather than 1+1=2 which is the desired outcome

Comment: Update your question with a How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we can reproduce what is happening.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve